# Does testnet bitcoin wallet support redirections?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-wallet-app

We are trying to integrate bitcoin testnet wallet with react native dapp usin deep linking. Such that when user tries to send btc he will be directed to bitcoin testnet wallet and once transaction is submitted user will be redirected back to react native dapp.

tried following code sample :

deeplink used:

```
bitcoin:${bitcoinAddress}?amount=${amount}&label=${label}&message=${message}&r=${encodeURIComponent(
      redirectUrl
    )}&callback=${encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl)}
```

wallet app used:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet_test&hl=en&gl=US

```
import React, { AppState,useEffect } from "react";
import { Linking, View, Button } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const onPressHandler = () => {
    const bitcoinAddress = "2NCXR2f6QsrUf4Kfpz99bctNA96vUw9j4bP";
    const amount = "0.000001";
    const label = "Test transaction";
    const message = "This is a test transaction";
    const callbackUrl = "myapp://transaction_callback";
    const redirectUrl = "myapp://redirect_back";

    // Create the deep link URL with the callback and redirect URLs
    const deepLinkUrl = `bitcoin:${bitcoinAddress}?amount=${amount}&label=${label}&message=${message}&r=${encodeURIComponent(
      redirectUrl
    )}&callback=${encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl)}`;

    // Open the deep link URL in the user's Bitcoin wallet app
    Linking.openURL(deepLinkUrl);
  };

  function handleUrl(url) {
    // Handle the deep link URL here
    console.log('Received deep link:', url);
  }
  
  function handleAppStateChange(appState) {
    if (appState === 'active') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        console.log("test herrr")
        handleUrl(url)
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

  }, []);

  return (
    // your app code here
    <View>
      <Text>test</Text>
      <Button title="Press me" onPress={onPressHandler} color="#841584" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Are there any other wallets which support redirections back to dapp and which support testnet?

Comment: I dont think the wallet you shown support deep linking, you can look into Blockstream Green Wallet who support it or also building a custom Testnet wallet within your React Native dApp using a library like bitcoinjs-lib